# How to format a decimal number as hex and store it in a string in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a hexadecimal number, stored as a string, that I need to increment and store back as a string. Currently I am doing this:

```PowerShell
# Reads the Firmware version from fwver.h

$fwver = $(Select-String -Path .\Dream\fwver.h -Pattern 'FWVER' -CaseSensitive)
$fwver = $fwver.ToString()
$fwver = [uint32]$fwver + 1
$fwver = $fwver.ToString()
echo $fwver
```

This outputs "794"

Trying to use Format-Hex like this:

```PowerShell
$fwver = Format-Hex -InputObject $fwver
```

Returns "0000000000000000   1A 03 00 00                                      ��"

My initial string is "0x0319" and I need that to become "0x031A". How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `$incrementedVersionAsHex = '0x{0:X4}' -f ([uint32]$fwver + 1)`

Comment: @Theo While this returns the correct format, the value is not incremented. I get 0x0319 as an output.

Comment: Yes it does. If as you say your initial value for `$fwver` is indeed `0x0319`.. `'0x{0:X4}' -f ([uint32]"0x0319" + 1)` --> `0x031A`

Comment: @Theo Yep, my bad. I was printing the wrong variable. Thank you!